# Swift: AnyClass variable that conforms to protocol

Tags: swift, generics, swift2

I have a static function I want to call on a class conforming to a protocol.

```
protocol P {
    static func f();
}

class C: P {
    static func f() {}
}
```

Is there a way to store `C.self` as a variable with a type that conforms to the protocol? Below does not compile, but it's what I'm ideally trying to do:

```
let a: AnyClass<P> = C.self;
a.f();
```

Comment: Why cant you just use the protocol as the type? `let a: P = C.self`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The type of the object you are trying to store with `C.self` is `C.Type`.

The Type `C` conforms to the protocol `P`

If you want to store your object by ensuring it conforms to `P`, use `P.Type` as the type.

Example:

```
let myObject: P.Type = C.self;
myObject.f();
```